# How to load Zaraz manually in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, cloudflare

i am trying to get the Zaraz Script working on a Nextjs Site which **can not** use the cloudflare proxy (orange) setting.
Following the documentation https://developers.cloudflare.com/zaraz/advanced/load-zaraz-manually I disabled auto injection and added the script in _app.js:

```
import Script from 'next/script'
return <Script src="https://capsloq.de/cdn-cgi/zaraz/i.js"></Script>
```

The `<script>` Tag is rendered within the `<head>` of the website.
But the `<script src>` just points to a 404 Page, not actually loading the script. Is Nextjs Page Router interfering with it? Or am I missing a basic thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the domain https://capsloq.de is not proxied by Cloudflare. Check the docs at this link https://developers.cloudflare.com/zaraz/advanced/domains-not-proxied.

Comment: I did follow that but reading it again i am noticing that i skipped the subdomain part. Thank you that was it